# Not able to fill a DropDownList according to the selection of another DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Respected sirs

I am using a `DropDownList` control and binding it to a `LinqDataSource`.

According to the selection of the mentioned `DropDownList`, I need to bind another `DropDownList` control.

I have handled the `SelectedIndexChanged` event for first `DropDownList`. When this `SelectedIndexChanged` occurs, page is getting refreshed. To prevent page from beend refreshed, I am using an `UpdatePanel` control. But, still the second `DropDownList` not loading.

Please give me a solution.

Thanks
Saravanaa

Answer (score 0):

Place the second `DropDownList` inside the `UpdatePanel`.

You may want to consider using [CascadeDropDown](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx) too.

Comment: I have placed second drop down list inside update panel also.that also not working

Comment: <asp:updatepanel id="up" runat="server" datatextfield="xxx" datavaluefied="yyy" datasource="linqdatasource" onSelectIndexchanged="ddl_selecindexchanged" autopostback="true">

Comment: For Second Dropdownlist <asp:Radcombobox id="as" runat="server">